# Nagios webinterface error..You don't have permission to access /nagios/ on this server

Tags: nagios

I am getting the below error when I am accessing the web interface of nagios.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /nagios/ on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at localhost Port 80

Please help me .. I am working from one week still not resolved.

Comment: Have you checked `/nagios/` folder permissions?

Comment: Thanks for your resopnce... i given 777 for nagios folder
you can find below
drwxrwxrwx. 9 nagios nagios 4096 Oct 11 23:02 nagios

nagios installed in /usr/local/nagios

Answer (score 0):

Couple of places to visit in the configuration files.

check your /etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf file , if the option for SSL is turned on ,try disabling it 
then
restart httpd service.

below is the sample entry from the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf

```
   ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/lib64/nagios/cgi"

<Directory "/usr/lib64/nagios/cgi">
#SSLRequireSSL
Options ExecCGI
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthName "Nagios Access"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
Require valid-user
</Directory>

Alias /nagios "/usr/share/nagios"

  <Directory "/usr/share/nagios">
   #SSLRequireSSL
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```